# Template function polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I am making some template numerical array classes that make it easy to do mathematical operations.  For instance, you could do something like the following to go from linear values to dB:

```
buf = 10 * buf.log10();
```

I would like to change methods like "log10" to non-member template functions that take a DspBuffer reference as an argument.  Aesthetically I think that would be a lot nicer because then the previous code would look like this:

```
buf = 10 * log10(buf);
```

The only problem with this approach is that some classes inherit from DspBuffer, like FixedPtDspBuffer (when using fixed point data types) and ComplexDspBuffer (for complex values).  I sometimes need to overload the functions, and I'm not sure that I can do that with non-member template functions.  For instance, with log10() and fixed point I would like to round the result of the underlying log10 result instead of implicitly doing a "floor" when converting back to fixed point.

Can I overload non-member template functions by making them more specific (i.e. one takes a DspBuffer, and one takes a FixedPtDspBuffer that inherits from DspBuffer), or is this doomed to failure?

Comment: You may look at [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly provide overloads to free functions such as your `log10` that respectively take a `DspBuffer&` or a `FixedPtDspBuffer`, etc. However unless your local code knows that it's working on the subclass, templates or not, those overloads won't be invoked. So the free function near equivalent of a virtual method call will always call the chosen base class overload.

One approach to get the virtual-style dispatch back would be to implement a virtual method on the object that the free function calls. If desirable, you could mark the method protected or private and the function a friend. Python does this sort of thing a lot, actually, with free function calls like `len(obj)` that in turn call `obj.__length__()`.

(I think this is architecturally similar to the Visitor pattern that Jarod42 suggested, but it doesn't hold itself to the names accept and visit.)